# why I get unreachable host with ansible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible

I have two machine, local host ubuntu, and client centOS 7.

I have added those lines into: /etc/ansible/hosts

```
[linux]
192.168.122.1
[linux:vars]
ansible_user=user
ansible_password=123456
```

and changed uncommented 1 line in ansible.cfg:

```
# uncomment this to disable SSH key host checking
host_key_checking = False
```

Still when I do:

```
ansible all -m ping

   192.168.122.1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.1 port 22: Connection timed out",
unreachable": true
}
```

what should I do ?
the password and user in hosts file is what i use to log into the other machine

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewalls and selinux. Port 22 is not accepting the connection. It's not a password issue, it's a networking issue.

Comment: what should I need to check in my firewalls?

Comment: If port 22 is open between your ansible server and the node

Comment: I tried with telnet and i got that connection timed out